# How to find the median vector out of 3 column vector?

Tags: matlab

I have 3 column vectors a,b &c and I have to find the median vector in matlab i.e, if e.g, 'a' is the median vector then the prgram would give the output as 'a'.
How can i do this?

Comment: what is the median vector? do you do sum of each value in a b & c and then do the median?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
%initializes input
k=5; a = rand(k,1); b = rand(k,1); c = rand(k,1);

%calcualtes median value
medRes = median([a,b,c],2);

%calculate output string
res = repmat('c', k, 1);
res(medRes==a) = 'a';
res(medRes==b) = 'b';
```

Results:

```
[a b c] =

0.7060    0.8235    0.4387
0.0318    0.6948    0.3816
0.2769    0.3171    0.7655
0.0462    0.9502    0.7952
0.0971    0.0344    0.1869

res = 
a
c
b
c
a
```

Comment: Dear droco! Its just concatinating the vectors and then calculating the median for each row. But what i need is at one sample time , out of three vector elements, the median value is given out. Lets say out of a(1), b(1) and c(1) if c(1) is median then give the output value of c(1)

Comment: I think that I understand now. I updated my answer. is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks droco..........  that was really helpfull :)

Comment: and if i want to get the values of res to form the median output signal, how then?

Comment: if you want the value in the i'th location, simply write res(i).
is this what you meant?

Comment: res(i) will give me back the character of vector as a, b or c but i was asking to retrieve their values

Comment: like in your case, res(5) shall give value as 'a' but I need 0.0971

Comment: ok i got that how to to do... thanks alot